# Attach event hover with on() method does not work

Tags: jquery

```
$("button#main-navbar-toggler").on("hover",function(){
    $(this).css({"color":"#6c757d","background-color":"#fff"});
    },
    function(){
    $(this).css({"color":"#6c757d","background-color":"#fff"});
    }
);
```

I attach event hover with on() method, but it does not work.

Comment: did you run this after document is ready ? and put your html also, thank you.

Comment: Yes, I put inside $(document).ready(function(){}.

Sorry, I don't understand your second question "and put html also"

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#main-navbar-toggler").hover(function(){
    $(this).css({"color":"#6c757d","background-color":"#fff"});
 
});
});
```

```css
#main-navbar-toggler{padding:5px; background-color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="main-navbar-toggler">Button</button>
```

Comment: I have used this way, but it could not be turned off using off() method.

 As what @Shyam Babu Kushwara said, so I use:

`$("button#main-navbar-toggler").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).css({"color":"#506b79","background-color":"#fff"});
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).css({"color":"#506b79","background-color":"#fff"});
    }
  });
`

Answer (score 1):

When using jQuery's

```
$(selector).on('event', function(){
    //code
});
```

you can pass only one handler. So if you want your code to work, just use hover() method as suggested by others.

Read more here: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

you can do it even without jquery , simple use css hover if you want to get back original style after hover is off

```css
#main-navbar-toggler{
padding:5px; 
background-color:orange;
}

#main-navbar-toggler:hover{
background-color:red;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="main-navbar-toggler">Button</button>
```